# Django: prefetch_related has no effect

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-performance

I'm trying to optimize a DB query using `prefetch_related` without success.

#### models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # some fields ...

    @property
    def last_operation(self) -> Optional['OrderOperation']:
        try:
            return self.orderoperation_set.latest()
        except OrderOperation.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def total(self) -> Optional[Decimal]:
        last_operation = self.last_operation
        return last_operation.total if last_operation else None

class OrderOperation(TimeStampable, models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    total = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

#### Running a shell, I can see the problem:

```
orders = Order.objects.prefetch_related('orderoperation_set')  # There are 1000 orders
result = sum([order.total for order in orders])
len(connection.queries)
>>> 1003
```

As we can see, there is one query per `order.total`, so 1000 queries, that makes the whole request very bad, with performance linear to the number of orders.

Trying to understand why this is happening, I found this in the [prefetch_related Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.

So, it seems normal that calling `latest()` each time run a new query.

**How would you do to improve performance in this case?** (making a few queries instead of N, with N is the number of orders).

Answer (score 1):

Since OrderOperation only contains a single relevant field, `total`, a better approach would be to annotate the total of the latest operation in the original query using a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
newest = OrderOperation.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')  # or whatever the timestamp field is
orders = Order.objects.annotate(newest_operation_total=Subquery(newest.values('total')[:1]))
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman, I'll try to implement it asap. Can you take a look to my own answer to this question, to compare it with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer here, can you tell me if this makes sense or not?

Instead of calling `latest()`, what if I simply get the first item in my queryset with `[0]` (or the last with `len(qs)-1`, supposing that order_operations are already ordered?

```
@property
def last_operation(self) -> Optional['OrderOperation']:
    try:
        qs = self.orderoperation_set.all()
        return qs[len(qs) - 1]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: A potential issue is that you are always retrieving all operations from the db, when you only need one. That's a lot of unncessary load.

Comment: You're right. Thought, knowing that in the real world, `orderoperation_set.all()` should return 1 result 95% of the time, and never more than 3, would it be an acceptable solution?